# Javascript form not submitting as expected on IE

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a function that creates a form in javascript and submits it.
It works as expected in Safari, Chrome, FF, & Opera but not IE 10.

When the from submits the browser is not pointed to the url in the action attribute in IE. I'm sure this is lame but I can't find the problem so any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
function checkout() {
    var myDoc = 'some xml data to send'
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.setAttribute( "method", "POST" );
    form.setAttribute( "action", "http://domain.com/script.php" );
    var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
    hiddenField.setAttribute( "type", "hidden" );
    hiddenField.setAttribute( "name", "myField" );
    hiddenField.setAttribute( "value", myDoc );
    form.appendChild(hiddenField);
    form.submit();
}
```

Thanks for any help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating the form, but you're not appending it to the document.

Add

```
document.documentElement.appendChild(form);
```

just before

```
form.submit();
```

Comment: Thanks so much, it's always the obvious the eludes me.